# FRC RoboRio Eclipse can't find edu.wpi.first.wpilibj

Tags: microcontroller, wheeled-robot

The first time after importing a project into the Eclipse workspace we find that eclipse cannot find the WPILIBj.

On any import line:`import edu.wpi.first.wpilibj.*` Eclipse says "unresolved import edu.

Comment: In this case the issue can be solved by creating a new Robot Java Project

Answer (score 2):

WPILib dev here. There's no need to recreate the project, although that will fix the problem. Simply right click on the project, click on properties > Java Build Path > Libraries > Add External Jar
Navigate to the wpilib folder on your computer and find the wpilibj.jar file. Select that file, and clean the project.

This won't fix things if you didn't start out with a wpilibj project because you'll be missing other files like build.properties and build.xml, but if you just lost the wpilibj jar file this will resolve that.

Comment: please accept this answer if it solved your problem.